# In kotlin how to make a class that map with keys from an Enum

Tags: generics, kotlin, enums

*Or to put another way, how to construct an internal EnumMap inside my class, where the EnumMap key types are set from the caller's choice of Enum.*

I was hoping to have code like:

```
enum MY_FLAGS { FLAG1, FLAG2, FLAG3 }
val myProfiler = Profiler<MY_FLAGS>()
myProfiler.profile(FLAG1) {
  longRunningOperation() 
  // the time to execute longRunningOperation 
  // is accumulated in myProfiler's EnumMap.
}
```

I've got a class that keeps track of various counters.  Those counter keys are always from the same Enum class.  So I'd like to construct the counter class instance to handle just that particular Enum.

So far I have `class Profiler<in E:Class<Enum<*>>>(private val clazz: E) {` which feels **really close**, but not quite it, because when I try to increment one of the counters using a Profiler class function, I can't quite use the E!

Like if TempEnum wasn't hardcoded into this:

```
val enumMap = EnumMap<TempEnum, MutableList<TimeDuration>>(TempEnum::class.java).apply {
  putAll(TempEnum.values().map {
    it to mutableListOf<TimeDuration>()
  })
}
```

Then the compile starts complaining about in vs out vs invariant, which is where I get fuzzy.

Answer (score 2):

To construct a class which can take a generic `Enum` as type parameter you can do the following:

```
class Profiler<E : Enum<*>> {
   val counter = mutableMapOf<E, Int>()

   fun profile(key: E, block: (E) -> Unit) {
        block(key)
        // increase counter
    }
}
```

This can be invoked using:

```
fun main() {
    val profiler = Profiler<MyFlags>()
    profiler.profile(MyFlags.Flag2) {
        println("$it - ${profiler.counter[it]}")
    }
}
```

---

To restrict the `Profiler` to only accept `MyFlags` as valid type parameter, you can change the class signature as follows:

```
class Profiler<E : Enum<MyFlags>> {
```

Comment: "`class Profiler<E : Enum<MyFlags>>`" (or simpler `class Profiler<E : MyFlags>)` This doesn't make much sense. Why have a type parameter with only one possible value? Just remove the type parameter and use `MyFlags`!

Comment: I don't quite get how this works with an EnumMap: `class  Profiler<E : Enum<*>>(clazz: E) { 
    val counter = EnumMap<E,  Int>(clazz)`